# How to join two areas using python?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, video-sequence-editor

I'm working on a script which should add a trim mode to the sequencer. The preview area is split into two preview areas, until the trimming has finished and the two areas are joined again, but I can't figure out how to get the values needed for the area_join function right. How do I get the script to join the two areas into one area again?

Some example code:

```
import bpy

original_area = bpy.context.area

for region in original_area.regions:
    print(region.type)
    if region.type == 'WINDOW':
        old_area_x=region.x
        old_area_y=region.y

start_areas = bpy.context.screen.areas[:]

bpy.ops.screen.area_split(direction='VERTICAL', factor=0.5) # Split

#[Here things will happen(modal trimming) in the two preview areas before they will be joined into one again]

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area not in start_areas:
        new_area=area

for region in new_area.regions:
    print(region.type)
    if region.type == 'WINDOW':
        new_area_x=region.x + region.width 
        new_area_y=region.y + region.height 

print("ox "+str(old_area_x))
print("oy "+str(old_area_y))
print("nx "+str(new_area_x))
print("ny "+str(new_area_y))

# I'm not sure I understand these values right?
bpy.ops.screen.area_join(min_x=old_area_x, min_y=old_area_y, max_x=new_area_x, max_y=new_area_y) #Join - not working
```

A few words on what I need this function for: https://blenderartists.org/t/wip-vse-quick-functions-snaps-fades-zoom-parenting-titling-play-speed/611831/93

[image: Trim-mode for Sequencer]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a script by dustractor, which adds a toggle button to the header of the 3d View which splits and joins the area: [https://github.com/dustractor/areatype_split/blob/master/**init**.py](https://github.com/dustractor/areatype_split/blob/master/__init__.py)

The values of the working(vertical) area_join function seems to be:

- min_x = Left x of left window
- min_y = Mouse position, starting from window bottom y (when clicking button)
- max_x = X position between left and right window
- max_y = Mouse position, starting from window bottom y (when clicking button)

Here's my version, with a working button in the sequencer header area:

```
bl_info = {
        "name": "Areatype Trim",
        "description":"This example adds a button which toggles a split of an area with another.",
        "author":"dustractor@gmail.com, tintwotin",
        "version":(0,1),
        "blender":(2,65,0),
        "location":"Button prepended to the header of the sequencer.",
        "warning":"",
        "wiki_url":"",
        "category": "Sequencer"
        }

import bpy


class AREATYPE_OT_trim(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "areatype.trimview"
    bl_label = "Trim"

    def execute(self,context):
        thisarea = context.area
        otherarea = None
        tgxvalue = thisarea.x + thisarea.width + 1
        thistype = context.area.type
        arealist = list(context.screen.areas)
        for area in context.screen.areas:
            if area == thisarea:
                continue
            elif area.x == tgxvalue and area.y == thisarea.y:
                otherarea = area
                break
        if otherarea: #leave trim-mode
            bpy.ops.screen.area_join(min_x=thisarea.x,min_y=thisarea.y,max_x=otherarea.x,max_y=otherarea.y)
            print("this x: "+str(thisarea.x))   #min_x = left x of left window 
            print("this y: "+str(thisarea.y))   #min_y = mouse position, starting from window bottom y
            print("other x: "+str(otherarea.x)) #max_x = x between left and right window
            print("other y: "+str(otherarea.y)) #max_y = mouse position, starting from window bottom y

            bpy.context.space_data.overlay_type = 'CURRENT' 
            bpy.ops.screen.screen_full_area()
            bpy.ops.screen.screen_full_area()
            return {"FINISHED"}
        else: # enter trim-mode
            bpy.context.space_data.overlay_type = 'REFERENCE'          
            areax = None
            bpy.ops.screen.area_split(direction="VERTICAL")
            for area in context.screen.areas:
                if area not in arealist:
                    areax = area
                    break
            if areax:
                areax.type = thistype
                return {"FINISHED"}
        return {"CANCELLED"}


def draw_func(self,context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.operator("areatype.trimview",text="Trim",icon="ARROW_LEFTRIGHT")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(AREATYPE_OT_trim)
    bpy.types.SEQUENCER_HT_header.prepend(draw_func)   

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(AREATYPE_OT_trim)
    bpy.types.SEQUENCER_HT_header.remove(draw_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

This is where I am with the trim-script right now: https://gist.github.com/tin2tin/b7fd08762d1d8290626ee299488e2798

[image: Gif]