# How to remove or join two areas with python?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, add-on

I’m trying to remove a specific area from the screen. There doesn’t seem to be a simple .remove, so I looked for other options.

I found this ([How to join two areas using python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120479/how-to-join-two-areas-using-python)) which would have worked fine, but the operator changed in 2.8, so it doesn’t work anymore.
Is there a good way to remove an area with a script?

Comment: Somewhat related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161725/what-context-should-be-passed-to-screen-area-move-to-make-it-work/161786#161786

Comment: @batFINGER This seems to work for moving areas but I can't get it to work for joining.