# How to close an area using python

Tags: python, interface

How to close specific area types down using python.
Definitely don't want to switch area types, or be jumping in out fullscreen mode?

Close Vertically? or Close Horizontally? Since Blender developers already use the principle, top to bottom, left to right. Then why don't we just start from the top?

[image]

Here is a basic example of it working. The above illustration is what should be really focused on though. closing down a middle window.

[image]

Any guidance on this would be amazing. Thank you

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken in blender you can't "close" an area, you have to join it to an existing one. But I dont even know if that's exposed to the API

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120479/how-to-join-two-areas-using-python  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/161786/15543

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161983/operator-tooltip-from-layout-text

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to override context to not close the area in which you are working:
here is an example that you can run from Text editor:

```
import bpy

override_context = bpy.context.copy() 
area = [area for area in bpy.context.screen.areas if area.type == "NODE_EDITOR"][-1]     
override_context['window'] = bpy.context.window
override_context['screen'] = bpy.context.screen
override_context['area'] = area
override_context['region'] = area.regions[-1]
override_context['scene'] = bpy.context.scene


areas = [area for area in bpy.context.screen.areas if area.type == "NODE_EDITOR"]


for area in areas:
    bpy.ops.screen.area_close(override_context)
```